# Meaning of a quote in the movie Casino (1995)

Tags: quotes

I am watching Martin Scorcese's movie Casino (1995) and there is lot of idioms. I am not native english speaker so I am searching for the meaning of quotes I didnt know already. I found meaning of most of them but I cant find meaning of the last two sentences in this one (in bold):

*"The little guy. He's half in the bag, and nobody told him he was eighty-sixed from the joint, so we all turned our heads and made out like we didn't know who he was. He's over at the twenty-one table with his nose wide open. **He took the money out of his own kick. His nose is open for about ten thousand.**"*

I thought "nose wide open" has something to do with using cocaine but it doesnt make much sense. Thanks for explanation of the meaning.

Comment: It's a boxing term meaning his nose (face) is unprotected and he could be soon to receive a knock-out punch. It's used metaphorically here, and suggests he stands to lose $10,000 at the gaming table.

Comment: @Robusto, can you turn that comment into an answer? It's more correct than the last half of Strauss's answer.

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

1. *"He's half in the bag"* - he's drunk.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/half+in+the+bag

2. *"Eighty-sixed from the joint"* - he was kicked out.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/86

3. *"With his nose wide open."*
   This is indeed an odd turn of phrase. It's generally used in the context of lust,

For example:

> Sam’s not dense. He’s got his nose wide open. It’s that Sally.

This example used here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+one%E2%80%99s+nose+wide+open

In this context, I take it to mean that he is **pursuing** ten thousand dollars. Perhaps he's **well on his way** to winning ten grand.

4. *"He took the money out of his own kick."*
   Kick refers to his pocket. He's paying out of pocket.

From https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kick:

> Slang. a pocket: He kept his wallet in his side kick.